# Android studio device detected but not reconized as an android device (ADB trouble)

Tags: android, adb

[image: device foud but not reconized]

mode debuggable is activated on phone how I can resolve this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved it was just adriver problem thank you alll

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).